# Did you tell her about the vacancy in your brain?

Tags: jokes

P.J. meets a girl at the park. He is very excited. He tells his siblings about her after coming home. His brother Gabe replies,

> Emma. Who's Emma?

P.J. answers,

> A vision. An angel. The girl who's moved into my heart.

Gabe continues,

> Did you tell her about the vacancy in your brain?

I think Gabe is making a joke. What's the part that's intended to make people laugh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Vacancy" is a concept meaning availability of a location (hotel room, apartment, conference room, etc). So a hotel might advertise "vacancy" meaning that it has rooms available, and "no vacancy" if it has no available rooms.

If a location is "vacant" it means you can move into it or use it, **because there is nothing in it right now**.

P.J. is using the analogy of the girl "moving into" his heart, meaning she is living in his heart (that is, he cares for her romantically). Gabe is extending the "moving in" analogy and joking that P.J.'s *brain* has a "vacancy"—meaning someone would be able to move in there as well—because it is **empty**, meaning there are no thoughts in it. (See the expression *empty-headed*.) It is commonly said that being in love prevents you from thinking rationally.